# yii2 not allow ajax to access session

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, node.js, yii2

I am trying to access yii2 session with nodejs 
here is my code --

**Node JS  :**

```
client.on("request_notification_count",function(e){
    //get letest feed id
    console.log(e); 
    request.get(e.url+"?_crsf="+e._csrf,function(err,res,body){
        console.log(body);
        socket.emit('noticount', body);     
    });
})
```

**YII2 MODEL :**

```
echo $userid = Yii::$app->user->id; 
        if (isset($userid)) {
         // My Logic
           // return $count;            
        }else{
            echo "User Not set";
        }
```

If I hit the URL directly on browser, it displays the user id but in case of node & ARC it says user not set.

Answer (score 0):

Try to examine the cookie PHPSESSID from your outer request and pass it into your inner request.

Very probable you could pass it as a get-parameter (that's convenient!), rather than as a cookie. However this ability depends on php.ini, as well as the cookie name. But default settings will let you do exactly what I said.

`_crsf` does not matter in your situation.